# Symfony 4 Simple Form Authentication With Constraint Validator

Tags: symfony, validation, security, authentication, recaptcha

I want to use ConstraintValidator in my custom login authentication (using SimpleForm) to validate google Recaptcha of this bundle [EWZRecaptchaBundle](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle) I have not an idea

`security.yaml` main firewall section:

```
    providers:
         default:
             entity:
                 class: App:User
                 property: phone
    main:
         pattern: ^/
         anonymous: ~
         provider: default
         simple_form:
               authenticator: App\Security\Authenticator\UserAuthenticator
               check_path: login
               login_path: login
               username_parameter: phone
               password_parameter: password
               use_referer: true
         logout:
               path: logout
```

I need to use [Validaitor](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle/blob/master/src/Validator/Constraints/IsTrue.php) in `App\Security\Authenticator\UserAuthenticator`

This is my Custom Authenticator (`App\Security\Authenticator\UserAuthenticator`):

```
//...

class UserAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        }
        catch (UsernameNotFoundException $exception) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException("invalid");
        }

        $isPasswordValid = $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $token->getCredentials());
        if ($isPasswordValid) {
            return new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
        }

        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException("invalid");
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code, please (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): security.yaml. Are you using this https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_password_authenticator.html ? show the code also. And which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: @FranckGamess Sorry for the bad question, I will edted my question.

Comment: Thanks, you want to use this validator https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle/blob/master/src/Validator/Constraints/IsTrueValidator.php ?

Comment: @FranckGamess yes i need this to validate the Recaptcha on login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [How to Create a Custom Authentication System with Guard](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html) for a simpler and more flexible way to accomplish custom authentication tasks like this.

Especially the **getCredentials** method of the **GuardAuthenticator** class that you will create.

> getCredentials(Request $request)
>       This will be called on every request and your job is to read the token (or whatever your "authentication" information is) from the request and return it. These credentials are later passed as the first argument of getUser().

**or whatever your "authentication" information is** so you will be able to handle the value passed within the recaptcha.

```
<?php

namespace App\Security\Authenticator;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class FormLoginAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $encoder;

    /**
     * @var ValidatorInterface
     */
    private $validator;

    /**
     * FormLoginAuthenticator constructor.
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder
     * @param IsTrueValidator $isTrueValidator
     */
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder, ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Return the URL to the login page.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return '/login';
    }

    /**
     * Does the authenticator support the given Request?
     *
     * If this returns false, the authenticator will be skipped.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return mixed Any non-null value
     *
     * @throws \UnexpectedValueException If null is returned
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $violations = $this->validator->validate($request->request->get('g-recaptcha-response'), new IsTrue()); 
        if($violations->count() > 0){ 
            throw new AuthenticationException(self::INVALID_RECAPTCHA); 
        }
        return array(
            'username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Return a UserInterface object based on the credentials.
     *
     * The *credentials* are the return value from getCredentials()
     *
     * You may throw an AuthenticationException if you wish. If you return
     * null, then a UsernameNotFoundException is thrown for you.
     *
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     *
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     *
     * @return UserInterface|null
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {

        return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['username']);
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the credentials are valid.
     *
     * If any value other than true is returned, authentication will
     * fail. You may also throw an AuthenticationException if you wish
     * to cause authentication to fail.
     *
     * The *credentials* are the return value from getCredentials()
     *
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param UserInterface $user
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     */
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $plainPassword = $credentials['password'];

        if (!empty($plainPassword) && !$this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $plainPassword)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException();
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication executed and was successful!
     *
     * If you return null, the current request will continue, and the user
     * will be authenticated. This makes sense, for example, with an API.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @param string $providerKey The provider (i.e. firewall) key
     *
     * @return Response|null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Make sure your authenticator is registered as a service. If you're using the [default services.yaml](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-container-services-load-example) configuration, that happens automatically. So you will be able also to pass the EWZRecaptchaBundle validator in the constructor of the GuardAuthenticator, then you can use it to validate the recaptcha value before sending the username and the password in **getCredentials**

and change security.yaml like this:

```
providers:
     default:
         entity:
             class: App:User
             property: phone
main:
     pattern: ^/
     anonymous: ~
     provider: default
     guard:
         authenticators:
             - App\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
     logout: ~
```

Comment: This means to write the code of validator in my authentication process in GuardAuthenticator?

Comment: Yes but not all the logic. The validator has a **validate** method which take the value to validate and the constraint as parameters

Comment: Would you show me some code of using the validator, please?

Comment: I test and get this error `Too few arguments to function EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsTrueValidator::__construct(), 0 passed in ` on this line `$this->isTrueValidator->validate($request->request->get('_recaptcha'), new IsTrueValidator())` and the valid function return void.

Comment: @A.Seddighi please comment with the changes so I will update the answer

Comment: Change this `$this->isTrueValidator->validate($request->request->get('_recaptcha'), new IsTrueValidator())` to `$violations = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($request->request->get('g-recaptcha-response'), new IsTrue());
        if($violations->count() > 0){
            throw new AuthenticationException(self::INVALID_RECAPTCHA);
        }` and the `IsTrue()` is from EWZBundle (`EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue`)